# Download some of the artifacts files

Tags: github-actions, artifacts

I have the below github action snippet to upload files to the artifacts in a job.

```
      - name: Dist Packages Output artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: artifact
          path: ./*
          retention-days: 30
```

In another job I need to download some of the artifacts file (for example artifacts files include file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt and i want to download just file1.txt and file2.txt).

If I use the below snippet it will download all of them.

```
      - name: Download artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: artifact
          path: packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. But you can create a second artifact which contains only those few file and then download only this artifact.